# Oauth2 vs APIKey in a server to server communication

Tags: api, oauth2

A third party service provider is exposing a payment API that we need to integrate on our backend.
As transport communication we will consume this API using TLS with Client Certificate and over a MPLS private network.

As authentication framework, the third party is suggesting Oauth2;
I'm instead suggesting a "ligther" authentication like an APIKey/ClientSecret.
Why?
Because, from my "limited" experience, I don't see any benefits in using Oauth2 in this scenario.

- The Api will be consumed by just one single service user used by our backend.
- We don't have any level of authorization (no claims).
- In Oauth2, to protect credentials, you use them just to get an access token and you authenticate to the API using it; in our scenario, credentials are not personal credentials but a single service credentials provided by the third party API provider.
  Leaking them would be like leaking an APIKey from my point of view.
- In case of some security breach you will just have to revoke the APIKey; having 
  Oauth2, you have to revoke the refresh token leaving the granted access token 
  still valid.
- This will force us to create some utility library (based on Restsharp) and database tables to handle all the back and forth imposed by Oauth2 protocol. One thing that I saw in other projects is that this library need to be "synchronized" in case of concurrent access.

Probably I am missing some important points and my oversimplification is not admittable in an crucial service like a payment API.
In your experience, does Oauth2 have some advantages over a "basic authentication" in this specific scenario?

Comment: I'm facing the same case but in the other side, as initial choice I opted for API token which is tied to the client credentials. API token is less intrusive in term of integration.

Comment: Hey there. Did any of the answers help you out? If so please mark one as accepted, or open up the comments section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API key/client secret makes more sense for service to service communication, which seems to be your scenario from what I gather (your backend to their API service).

Having said that, OAuth 2 has a [client credentials grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4), which can do some sort of API key/client secret/certificate based authentication - check with your third party provider to see if they support it.

Usually OAuth 2 is associated with the [authorization code grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), which is good when the user agent is a browser since that was what it was designed for, but not appropriate for service to service.

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting topic and there are a couple of things to consider. First we need to come at it from the API provider, not *just* the consumer.

### Who?

The main consideration is Authentication vs. “Identity” and Permissions. Refresher:

- Identity = Who say you are
- Authentication = Who you really are
- Permissions = What you can do

Check out this [post](http://www.srimax.com/index.php/do-you-need-api-keys-api-identity-vs-authorization/) for more detail on API ID and Permissions.

While, in this instance permissions may be implicit (where by virtue of being authenticated you are able to use the API), consider this: As the provider of an API to a service with the level of sensitivity payments require, I want to *know* that the **consumer *is* who they say the are**.

Passing an API Key only confirms that you have the API Key: it does not prove that you are authorised to access the API.

Now, possessing an OAuth Access Token may initially be viewed the same, however the OAuth [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10) states

> The authorization server MUST authenticate the client whenever
> possible.

OAuth enables this by providing refresh token, as you said, along with a registered redirect URI. It also suggests a minimally scoped token for all initial and re-authentication requests.

This gives the API provider much more control, more visibility and thus more confidence that their API has not been compromised.

OAuth also plays nicely with permissions. If the payment gateway company decided to extend authentication to require permissions to GET and to POST, this would be less work and more secure than if you had to try to tie a key to permissions.

### Exposure

A secondary but relevant consideration is what to do if the API Key is exposed.

I know I want be able to trust the key, however it might have been breached. So I also whitelist the clients IP... IP’s can change, depending on configuration, and they can also be spoofed... How can I know if the key is being used nefariously or not?

If the API key is then re-issued post breach it can be easier for someone to determine possible new keys once the initial key is known. This means that the providers key gen algorithm may also need to be adjusted.

If you were issued an Access Token that somehow got exposed, once it comes up for refresh, the unauthorised user should not be able to get reauthorised. I can log them log this erroneous request and work with the consumer to diagnose root cause.

### Summary

The API key was only ever meant to serve as a [form](https://nordicapis.com/why-api-keys-are-not-enough/) of ID. As such they are basically misused when implemented as a primary security measure.

If API Consumers need to be authenticated - as in you need to verify the caller of the API and provide access to certain resources based on that verification - OAuth is the better choice.

Hope this helps!

---

**NB** For arguments sake, I have assumed no one has root access to your internal services or network, and all over-the-wire comms are via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true, it could happen. A replay attack is quite common but there are ways to implement it very safely. Your server should definitely use ip monitoring, which means once the token is issued it will only allow a specific IP but that doesn't solve the problem since the compromise can be from within. Second way is to minimize expiration time which narrows down the exposure risk. Lastly there's always WebSockets ... it usually syncs fast enough to issue new token per request, which eliminates most risk, since its for business use, use it on its own dedicated Vlan which can has only access to x port. ... etc etc

At the end of the day, you can bulletproof it all you want, you still can't survive a MITM attack, especially if root certificates have been compromised on your machine.